# recursively list all the csv files within a directory/subdirectory

Tags: bash, unix, sh, ksh, unix-timestamp

How to "recursively" list all the csv files with usernames and last access date within a directory.

something like

```
 filename            user          lastaccessdate
/bin/a.csv           dory            2013-12-12
/bin/apps/b.csv      nina             2014-01-01
```

Thanks

Comment: user = the csv file owner?

Answer (score 5):

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*.csv' -printf '%p\t%u\t%AY-%Am-%Ad\n'
```

Comment: `echo -e 'filename\tuser\tlastaccessdate'; find /some/path -type f -name '*.csv' -printf '%p\t%u\t%AY-%Am-%Ad\n'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to have a nice and proper display:

```
$(echo -e 'filename\tuser\tlastaccessdate'; find . -type f  -name '*.csv' -printf '%p\t%u\t%AY-%Am-%Ad\n')| column -t -s $'\t'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
filename                  user     lastaccessdate
./input.file.csv          arobert  2018-01-31
./abc.csv                 arobert  2018-01-31
./ab c.csv                arobert  2018-02-05
```

files with space in their name are also properly handled thanks to the following delimiter `$'\t'`